# Where can I find ETF fund flow data?

Tags: data

I know mutual fund data can easily be found on CRSP or Thomson Reuters, but where can I find solid ETF data, specifically their flows?

Comment: Bloomberg terminals have the .SO (shares outstanding) data for most (all?) ETFs.  You can deduce the flows from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy answer to this question. Several providers do provide partial solutions, but nothing that could be considered research-grade like CRSP's mutual fund data. Beyond holdings and flows, there are all sorts of variables one could be interested in when looking at ETFs, e.g. discount to NAV, creation/redemption baskets, etc.

Here's a partial list:

- [Thomson Reuters' Lipper](https://financial.thomsonreuters.com/en/products/data-analytics/financial-research/lipper-fund-research.html), which is now one of the primary sources for CSRP and is more detailed and up to date.
- [Factset's ETF Analytics](https://www.factset.com/analytics/etf_analytics) data, which in some cases goes back to 1993.
- [Morningstar's](http://corporate.morningstar.com/ca/asp/subject.aspx?page=4&xmlfile=2404.xml) historical data, which goes back to 2003.
- [CRSP Survivor-Bias-Free US Mutual Fund data](http://www.crsp.com/products/documentation/crsp-survivor-bias-free-us-mutual-fund-guide-crspsift), which includes US ETF data. There would be no information about ETF redemption baskets, for example.

Most of these options, except CRSP, cost in the hundreds of thousands of dollars a year. Depending on your purpose/affiliation/profile you could also try reaching out to the largest players and ask for historical data, which would not be exhaustive but probably a lot cheaper.

Note that I do not have access to all of this data and that the coverage can vary quite a bit between vendors. You should reach out to them for a sample and access to the data dictionary for their products. Sadly the marketplace for financial data is not very efficient.